# Jenkins EnvInject Plugin does not resolve $WORKSPACE

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, workspace

I want to inject a new path variable to a folder which resides in my project workspace.

`PATH=$PATH:$WORKSPACE/workspace-configuration/bin/sencha_cmd`

That's how I defined it in **Properties Content**

> [EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables
>   after the SCM step. [EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables
>   the properties content
>   PATH=/home/tomcat/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/java/latest/bin:$WORKSPACE/workspace-configuration/bin/sencha_cmd

As you can see the *$WORKSPACE* variable was not resolved

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prepare an environment for the run** needs to be checked in *General* settings of the Jenkins Job